# NullReferenceException from GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver.AutoResolve

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

Sorry for my pool English first.

I make my android game in Unity3d 5.5.0p4 with GoogleMobileAdsv3.1.3
and I got the error print in unity console loop infinity :

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver.AutoResolve ()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication.Internal_CallUpdateFunctions () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/editor/EditorApplicationBindings.gen.cs:197)
```

I already updated android SDK items which I need to the newest.
I don't know how to fix that.Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by delete some files which named **google*** from /project/ProjectSettings/

I wish my post helps everyone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case turned out that someone commited ProjectSettings/GoogleAarExplodeCache.xml with unresolved conflict and made that file unparsable.

Removing it and regenerating helped.